# Getting selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, sessionid

I am getting **Error of selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session-id** as soon as I am trying to find CheckboxClick web Element from inside a Function call defined in try block and when I placed below line of code outside the function and try block it will not throw me any error.

**Line of Code**

```
try:
    def getrecordsoNpage():
        **CheckBoxclick = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#workflow_table > thead > tr > th.first.checkbox-column.checkbox > input"))).click()**
        RecordsonOnePage = int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#wf_table_footer > form.inline.pull-left > div > label > span').text)
        pprint.pprint(RecordsonOnePage)

        totalnofpages = math.ceil(TotalNofRecord / RecordsonOnePage)
        print(totalnofpages)
        return RecordsonOnePage,totalnofpages

except RuntimeError as e:
    pprint.pprint(e)
finally:
    driver.close()
    # driver.quit()

RecordsonOnePage,totalnofpages = getrecordsoNpage()
pprint.pprint(RecordsonOnePage,totalnofpages)
```

Can Somebody please suggest why it is acting like that and ways I can correct that I have searched for Invalid session-id error and tried to dispose session id but getting the error as explained above.

Comment: I'm guessing you have `driver.close()` in previous function?

Comment: Hi, @Guy I have Driver.close() in finally block, I didn't get which previous function you are mentioning here.

Comment: Do you use `driver.close()` anywhere before calling `getrecordsoNpage()`? the error means you are using the `driver` after closing it.

Comment: @guy I am not using driver.close() anywhere before calling getrecordsoNpage()

Comment: I just noticed you have the function inside the `try except`. Why? it should be the other way around (and probably what causing your problem).

Comment: try removing your finally code and write after you call getrecordsoNpage method cause it is calling the method after there is no driver avalaible, hope this helps

Comment: Yes it helped.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed my function inside Try block and have placed try block inside my function and it helped to rectify that error and moreover the primary reason the error arose when we were using the driver after closing it.